# How to use multiple threads to execute the same code and speed up it?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm facing some performance issues to execute a fuzzy match based on Leveinshtein distance algorithm.

I'm comparing two lists, a small one with 1k lines and a second one with 10k lines.

I have splitted the bigger list in 10 files of 1000 lines to check speed performance, but I checked that Python is using only 1 thread.

I have googled for many articles and people says how to execute TWO different functions in paralel.

I would like to know how to execute the SAME code in multiple threads.

For example: it's taking 1 second to compare 1 word in a 1000 lines. I would like to split this time in 4 threads.

Is it possible?

Sorry for the long text and thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Running the same code in two or more threads won't assist performance. You could potentially split up the task so each handles 250, then have each thread handle 1 of those tasks. Then compare the results at the end.

Comment: Hum... good idea.
I will try to split in 2 or 4 the list and execute it. Thanks a lot!